# Check if a String is in a specific form JAVA

Tags: java, regex, string, compare

Lets say I have a string

```
String line = "Let x0 be {1,2,3,4}"
```

How can I check if it the String is written in "Let ??? be ???"

I was trying with the code below but I thing you need to know the length of the ??? to make it work

```
 matches = line.matches("Let \\d be \\d")
```

Thank you

Comment: Please define your grammar, if you want to find an embedded compiler, there is a lot of them, and you can generate your own compiler, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question, is it more clear what I am trying to do?

Comment: If it is in the right format then print true, otherwise false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d` only match digit, short for [0-9], it can't match `x0`, neither any char of `"{,}"` so you can match with `\S`, which means a non-whitespace character. and since you do not know the length, and expect at least one, can add "`+`" to \S, like `\S+`.
so this one can match your expect: `Let \S+ be .*`

Answer (score 1):

try this regex `"Let (\w+) be (\S+)"`

```
String line = "Let x0 be {1,2,3,4}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Let (\w+) be (\S+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
int lastMatchPos = 0;
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
   System.out.println(m.group(2));
   if(m.group(2).length> m.group(1).length){
        //do something you want
   }
}
```